# intent.putExtra passes empty value

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to develop a qr scanner where I want to show the history of scanned results to user. Now although the scanned data values are passed to a different activity properly; the problem with it is even if I have not scanned the qr the empty data is passed to the listview of the next activity.

**My question is how do I make sure that only if the qr is scanned the data is passed to the next activity in the listview?**

This is the code for my barcode activity.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
//Initialization
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
    ArrayList<String> listOfBarcodes = new ArrayList<String>();

//This is the part where I handle the result

     @Override
        public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {

            final String result = rawResult.getText();
            if(!result.isEmpty()) {
                //whenever you capture a new barcode add it to this list
                listOfBarcodes.add(result);
            }
```

P.S: After this am handling the result to show in AlertDialog.

The part where I am sending the data to next activity.

```
 Intent data = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), History.class );
                if (listOfBarcodes!=null) {
                data.putExtra("Barcode", listOfBarcodes);
            }
                startActivity( data );
```

**History.java**

```
public class History extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final ArrayList completeList = new ArrayList<String>();
TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        Intent callingIntent= getIntent();
        ArrayList<String> listOfBarcodes = callingIntent.getExtras().getStringArrayList("Barcode");
        completeList.add(listOfBarcodes);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aA = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, completeList);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list_id);
        lv.setAdapter(aA);
```

Apart from this I also do get the warning in `completeList.add(listOfBarcodes);`

> Unchecked call to 'add(E)' as a member of raw type
>   'java.util.ArrayList' less... (Ctrl+F1)  Signals places where an
>   unchecked warning is issued by the compiler, for example:
>
> void f(HashMap map) {
>       map.put("key", "value");   }

**In `History.java` the listview with empty value appears as []. Is there a different method to pass the data or am I missing something here?**

Comment: Did you try to make a condition before you get the array value from intent? Intent.hasExtra(String name).

Comment: @RobertBanyai I did try it. The problem is not about passing the data. it adds an empty value " [] " into the listview if it has not scanned anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `putStringArrayListExtra()`  as you are sending `ArrayList<String>`. First make sure list `listOfBarcodes` has the data.

```
Intent data = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), History.class );
    if(listOfBarcodes.size()!=0)
    data.putStringArrayListExtra("Barcode",listOfBarcodes);
    startActivity(data);
```

In History Activity:-

```
 ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list_id);
    Intent callingIntent= getIntent();
    if(callingIntent.hasExtra("Barcode")) {
        ArrayList<String> listOfBarcodes = callingIntent.getStringArrayListExtra("Barcode");
        completeList.addAll(listOfBarcodes);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aA = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, completeList);
        lv.setAdapter(aA);
    }else{
        // No scanned handle here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried it. The data however like I said in the question is passed. Nevertheless, the problem is it sends empty StringArray every time as [] into the listview if the scanner hasn't scanned anything.

Comment: That the possible behaviour . If scanner haven't scanned anything then list will be empty and it will pass empty . What's the point here ?

Comment: the point is when I am logging it into the listview the value **[]** is added in the listview.

Comment: Oh thanks it did handle the problem of empty string. But the warning still exists. Please refer the question.

Comment: Ok how to declared `completeList`? it should be as `ArrayList<String> completeList`.

Comment: Also you should use `completeList.addAll(listOfBarcodes);`.